# Internet Explorer not redirecting to HTTPS, other browsers work fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web.Release.config rewrite rule that redirects traffic to HTTPS, but it doesn't seem to work in IE. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Any idea what I'm missing? I've checked the IE Advanced Internet options and didnt see anything that looked wrong.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't use re-write anymore!

Just add this line bellow into you file `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs`:

```
filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
```

if you need to set the enviroment to only production:

```
#if !DEBUG
    filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
#endif
```